# How to auto size plots in R

Tags: r, statistics, plot

Say I have a huge decision tree by using the package `party`, how does one declare auto size to fit everything into a jpeg or png?

Example:

```
library(party)
data(Boston) 
jpeg("test.jpg")
tree <- ctree(crim ~ zn + indus + chas + nox + rm + age + dis + rad + tax + ptratio + black, data = Boston)
plot(tree)
```

Comment: Use png if you're going to use a raster format. Plots don't generally warrant compression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I think your problem here is that you aren't getting output. The reason is because of how graphics devices work. You have to open the file to write to, enter the data you want in the file, then close the graphics device.

For what you want to do:

```
png("test.png", 1200, 600)
plot(tree)
dev.off()
```

The numbers set the width and height of the png in pixels.

EDIT: If you want it to autosize, I suggest modifying it based on the number of terminal nodes:

```
png("test.png", 140*length(unique(tree@where)), 600)
plot(tree)
dev.off()
```

[image: auto-size]

Comment: I edited it as I realised it didn't quite answer your question. I think it does better now.